A question from the LIMIT 2021 exam about convergence of sequences
I came across this question in the LIMIT Exam (conducted by students of ISI Bangalore) 2021 paper.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be LIMIT-astic if given any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the sequence defined as $x_1 = x$, $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$ converges. Then which of the following functions is NOT LIMIT-astic?
(A) $f(x) = \cos{x}$
(B) $f(x) = x^{2021} −x^{2020} +\cdots−1$
(C) $f(x) = \{x\}^{[x]}$, $x > 0$ or $x\notin \mathbb{Z}$; $0$ otherwise. (Here, $\{·\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $[·]$ is the integral part.)
(D) Both (B) and (C) are not LIMIT-astic.

I tried to solve the question but was unable to proceed it would be really helpful if you could give me some hints on how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance...

Please add in whatever you have tried

Hints: for A and C, what are the images of the function, and how does the function behave (for A is the derivative majored) on its image. For B is the function increasing?
